# Seeking Simple JSOUP example with AsyncTask Implemented

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I'm attempting to find a simple example of JSOUP with AsyncTask implemented. I'm attempting to query a url for results (http://www.sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=&fname=) but I have yet to find a simple working example showing how this can be done when googleing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough outline to get you started -

Make a class

`private class AsyncTest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`

the first String is what will be passed to the task, in this case your URL. The second string is the result

Within the brackets make 3 methods - `onPreExecute()`, `String doInBackground(String... params)`, and `onPostExecute(String result)`.

In the first one do something to tell the user that a task is running in the background, ie spawn a dialog with a spinning wait, or reflect it on the main gui.

The second method accept the data you pass to it and runs on a separate thread processing it and returning a string.(It can return anything you want, you just have to set it in the class header.) In your scenario I'd fetch the URL and parse the data here. Return whatever information you need.

The last method returns to the gui thread and allows you to display the data you've received from the middle method.

The task is then run by calling `new UpdateZmanim().execute(urlString);`
There are other ways to call an AsycTask, but I've found this to be the best due to a limitation in the Async Class that only allows for an Asyc object to be run only once. To avoid this I recommend creating a `new` object each time you want to run it.

Note: You don't always have to use an AsycTask. Often a simple thread will suffice.

Hope this helps, Good Luck ;)

Comment: I appreciate the AsyncTask tutorial... (I still need to know how to use JSOUP to parse the data as well though!)

Comment: I need help using AsyncTask WITH JSOUP : )

Comment: calm down a bit. you have two separate tasks to do here. the async task, and within it the jsoup parser. i've laid out the async task, and jsoup usage in android can be found with any one of these links - https://www.google.com/search?q=JSOUP&oq=JSOUP&aqs=chrome.0.69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=jsoup+android+example&oq=JSOUP+and&gs_l=serp.3.1.0i20j0l2j0i20.5060.5841.0.7720.4.3.0.1.1.0.182.503.0j3.3.0....0.0..1c.1.20.psy-ab._E9FQGKCsS8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099%2Cd.cGE%2Cpv.xjs.s.en_US.c75bKy5EQ0A.O&fp=f6f4197e888c5ffe&biw=1920&bih=947